# Pycharm: Compile Cython Extensions Error - unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

On Ubuntu 14.04, I use Pycharm Professional Edition. When I start a debug session, I see the following message in the event log of Pycharm:

> Python Debugger Extension Available
>
> Cython extension speeds up Python debugging
>
> [Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3YrY.png)   [How does it work](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2018.3/cython-speedups.html?utm_content=2018.3&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=PY)

Clicking on `Install` leads to a popup window with an error message:

[image: error message]

I depict here the text, too, so that it can be found by others more easily:

> **Compile Cython Extensions Error**
>
> Non-zero exit code (1):
>
> unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

To look for a solution:

1. I compiled Cython speedups manually according to the link mentioned above: `/usr/bin/python3 /<PYCHARM_INSTALLATION_PATH>/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace`. This finishes successfully, but does not help with the error message.
2. I added the python-3.6-dev repository: 
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, executed: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
   and installed python-3.6-dev: `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`

   It finishes successfully, but does not change the above popup error message.

What else can I check or execute?

**EDIT**
regarding the installation of gcc, it looks like the following:

```
user@user-computer:~$ gcc
The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcc
user@user-computer:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libseccomp2 libwireshark5 libwiretap4 libwsutil4
  linux-image-3.13.0-160-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-160-generic
  linux-lts-xenial-tools-4.4.0-137 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-137-generic
  linux-tools-4.4.0-137-generic squashfs-tools
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
user@user-computer:~$ gcc
The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: Do you have gcc installed?

Comment: @Dinari  : I extended my question regarding the installation of `gcc`.

Comment: and after doing `sudo apt install --reinstall gcc` it works

Comment: Thanks for your good hint. Feel free to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:
`Cython` uses `gcc` (by default), need to verify it is installed and working properly.

As it installed by default on most recent `Ubuntu` distributions, if it is not working well, you can follow OP fix and use `sudo apt install --reinstall gcc`

Answer (score 5):

At first:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc
```

Then run commands below depends on version of `Python` , you are using:

For **Python 2.x** use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For **Python 3.x** use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

For **Python 3.8** use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

Comment: For those using pycharm, you must install the python<version>-dev according to the python interpreter set in your project.